# Is it possible to set GID/UID for Filestore in GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-filestore

I want to use FileStore in GKE by using PVC and PV based on this official doc: https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares

My app is not running as root, so I would like to set which GID/UID is used to mount the volume in the containers.

I know about some alternatives by using an InitContainer or a separate NFS middleware but will like to avoid another moving piece.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://serverfault.com/questions/906083/how-to-mount-volume-with-specific-uid-in-kubernetes-pod

Comment: thanks, @HelloWorld but I will like to avoid doing `chown` in each deploy, also, already using `securityContext` but the Filestore mount always is mounted as `root` while the main process run as unprivileged user hence the issue

Answer (score 1):

Kuberentes currently doesn't provide functionality to set volume mount permissions/owner using pod specification. All fields and their description can be found in [kubernetes api reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17).

The most often used method you can find on the internet is using initContiners. There doesn't really exist any other better method to do this.

You also mentioned that you would like to avoid doing chown in each deploy. You can avoid it using if statement in bash like in following example so that chown is executed only when necessary:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: my-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-pv-claim
  initContainers:
    - name: init-myservice
      image: busybox:1.28
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'OWNER=`stat -c "%U:%G" /mnt/data` && if [ $OWNER == "root:root" ]; then chown -R 1000:3000 /mnt/data; fi']
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mnt/data"
          name: my-pv-storage
  containers:
    - name: my-pv-container
      image: my-image
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/mnt/data"
          name: my-pv-storage
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 3000
```

Let me know it it was useful.

Comment: very useful thanks! still, I will like to avoid any "checking" as we are talking millions of files here. In my previous setup in Azure using azure disk it was possible to define mount options at StorageClass level to avoid all this

Comment: Yes, solving your issue with mount options will work only for some filesystems but unfortunately nfsv3 doesn't support options you need.

Comment: Also notice that my code is checking only top directory owner so it wont take long no matter how many files you have. It should work fine as long as you don't change uid every deployment.